# Why is deleting answers discouraged?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, deleted-answers

I deleted two answers of mine, because after some thinking I came to the conclusion those answers were not very good and/or not really my field of expertise:

1. [how to allocate more storage for home directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261680/how-to-allocate-more-storage-for-home-directory)

```
Edit: I agree with [kba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261944/151927) that using a partition manager to increase your home partition is not a good idea in your particular setup, because you would need to move your boot partition sda8 and that might cause problems. 

I have no idea how LVM works. That is why I cannot help you that much.

One last thing: You might want to consider using sda5 which has 800gb as your home partition if that is possible.


----------
You can increase the size of the partition where your /home directory is with a partition manager like gparted.

Since you already have linux installed, I would make a gparted Live USB key manually with the instructions on the following site: http://gparted.org/liveusb.php#linux-method-b

I recommend this method, because the other methods to create a Live USB key sometimes don't work (gparted won't boot).

Alternatively you can create a Ubuntu Live USB key with any version of unetbootin (Windows or linux version). It has gparted preinstalled.

I hope I understood your question right.

If you need more detailed instructions, I would gladly provide it.
```

2. [What does pwd output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261672/what-does-pwd-output)

```
I will answer my own question.

No, at the beginning of a shell script `pwd` returns the directory from which the shell script containing `pwd` is executed. This can be any folder in the computer. In the script you can call `cd` to enter different directories which changes the `pwd` to the directory the script entered.
```

They are bad answers and/or there were better answers, so I deleted them to improve the quality of this site. Why did I get minus 20 reps for them, and now I am stuck not being able to answer questions where I do have expertise, because I cannot ask for more details with comments?

Comment: When you deleted them, you lost the rep you obtained for those questions. I don't understand the title of your question. Why do you say that deleting answers is discouraged?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I did not have any upvotes for my answer in "What does pwd output?" and still lost 10 reps. But on the answer for "how to allocate more storage for home directory?" I had one upvote, but lost the same amount of rep (10).

Comment: That is incorrect. You got one upvote and one downvote on  "What does pwd output?", which gave you a total of 8 rep. 10 - 2. Michael has also pointed that out in his answer.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yes, right. There were some "-2" rep penalty and stuff that I did not understand, but the answer cleared that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't directly get or lose any reputation from deleting posts, but it does cancel out the reputation those posts gave. One of the answers was at +1/-0 upvotes/downvotes, and the other was +1/-1, so you'd received 18 rep total from those posts. You lose that rep when they're deleted, I assume because it would be odd to give credit for something that was undone. There's even a [badge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/disciplined) for deleting an answer you decide was bad even though it was upvoted, but yours weren't upvoted enough to qualify for it.

Fortunately, you're only a couple upvotes away from being able to comment again.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thanks! I am right now able to give comments, but that is only, because my answer to a duplicate question got accepted and upvoted... -_-

Comment: @mkdrive2 Oh, right. I was thinking it's 100 rep to comment, but it's only 50